# How can I avoid Complexity: O(n) for finding items in array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, search, time-complexity

I have a simple code of car racing, like in the code, the codes working fine right now and the result is fine as well, but I noticed I am using 2 ***Complexity: O(*n*)*** in my approach to overtake a car! Which I would wish do avoid multi ***Complexity: O(*n*)*** as possible, looking to know and learn, how i could do the same result with better performance in Complexity.

I do not want sort array for solving issue, the array should stay un sorted, because the order is important also not going use cpu power as well for sorting the array, because the array is large.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var cars: [CarType] = [CarType("A", rank: 5), CarType("B", rank: 3), CarType("C", rank: 1), CarType("D", rank: 2), CarType("E", rank: 4), CarType("Me", rank:6)]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            
            ForEach(cars, id:\.id) { car in
                Text(car.name)
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.5).cornerRadius(5.0))
                    .offset(x: 100 - Double(car.rank)*20)
            }
            .animation(.default, value: cars)
            
            Button("overtake") {
                
                if let myIndex: Int = cars.firstIndex(where: { car in car.name == "Me" }), cars[myIndex].rank != 1 {
                    if let overtakeIndex: Int = cars.firstIndex(where: { car in (car.rank == (cars[myIndex].rank - 1)) }) {
                        cars[myIndex].rank -= 1
                        cars[overtakeIndex].rank += 1
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            Button("use wormhole") {
                
                if let myIndex: Int = cars.firstIndex(where: { car in car.name == "Me" }), cars[myIndex].rank != 1 {
                    if let overtakeIndex: Int = cars.firstIndex(where: { car in (car.rank == 1) }) {
                        cars[overtakeIndex].rank = cars[myIndex].rank
                        cars[myIndex].rank = 1
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
            Button("reset") {
                
                cars = [CarType("A", rank: 5), CarType("B", rank: 3), CarType("C", rank: 1), CarType("D", rank: 2), CarType("E", rank: 4), CarType("Me", rank:6)]
                
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: 200)
        .padding()
        .overlay(Text(""), alignment: .trailing)

    }
}

struct CarType: Equatable {
    
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String
    var rank: Int
    
    init(_ name: String, rank: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It's not about Swift I would say. It's about your data structure/what you pick to use. A search that runs below O(n) is either heap, binary, or could be quick sort. You need to explore more for your app.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot use sort, the order should stay what it is.

Comment: Is the `rank` a property of the `Car`? Or is it a property of the race? (I know it's a property of the car in your code, I'm just asking whether it actually should be). You could store your data like... `[CarType: Int]`. i.e. a dictionary of `CarType` to `rank` and use that to access each car in `O(1)` time. Given that your array doesn't seem to have any sort of relevant order to the rank. It's just a collection of cars that needs to somehow be used to access the rank of a car,

Comment: Oh... hmm... you need to find the other car too... Hmm...

Comment: A dictionary cannot be used, because the order is important, otherwise that would be good approach.

Comment: There is a OrderedDictionary in Swift also.  Although, it wouldn't necessarily help in this case. I wonder if what you want is something more akin to a `linked list`. Or something.

Comment: OrderedDictionary? you mean the one in GitHub? I already know about that in my last questions, In the fact i want use apple free api comes with xcode, if it is possible.

Comment: Yeah, the one in the swift collections. You don’t have to pay for it and it’s still written by apple. 